# WinUI3 OPOS integration

Tags: winui-3, opos, pos-for-.net

I am developing a windows app using WinUI and .net framework 6.0. For integrating with a pos printer , i am using Pos For .Net Framework. Sample print applications provided with Epson OPOS ADK for .net is verified working . But when i try to use this from a WinUI3 page , i am getting exception

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried adding the reference to Forms dll and its throwing error related to version 4.0.0.
Also i tried enabling forms from project properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#usewindowsforms) . This was also causing additional errors related to *PresentationCore* and *PresentationFramework* dlls. Is there any reference for doing OPOS integration from a WinUI3 project ?

Comment: This library has not been updated since 2017 and is not being ported to .NET Core/5/6+ The reason being POS functionality is now in the Windows Runtime https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice so accessible from all .NET

Comment: Probably can not integrate. As an alternative, if possible, how about creating separate process that uses OPOS/POS for.NET and process that implements other functions such as the UI, and then combine them with the Inter Process Communication function to form a single application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at **Epson OPOS ADK** download page and it seems that it supports .NET Framework 4.0 or later, but doesn't support .NET 6 or later which is required for WinUI 3.

I have never tried this but I guess you should try wrapping the **Epson OPOS ADK** with a [.NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0#:%7E:text=if%20you%20want%20to%20share%20code%20between%20.NET%20Framework%20and%20any%20other%20.NET%20implementation%2C%20such%20as%20.NET%20Core%2C%20your%20library%20should%20target%20.NET%20Standard%202.0) project. It's suppose to work.

Comment: Thanks Andrew . I was trying to use Pos for .net https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55758 for integration from the app using OPOS . It says ".NET Framework 4.0 and above" as requirement . Any info on using POS for .Net with WinUI3

Comment: Sorry. I'm not familiar with this but [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/676599/what-are-the-alternatives-to-pos-for-net-on-net-6#:~:text=This%20library%20is%20not%20being%20upgraded%20to%20.net%20core.%20Most%20of%20the%20functionality%20is%20now%20in%20the%20runtime) might help.